# How can I have a template "view" in CodeIgniter 2.0?

Tags: codeigniter-2

I guess it's a view within a view, but I'd rather it happen automatically. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates, or layouts as they are often called in various MVC frameworks, can be achieved a number of ways in CodeIgniter, but ultimately in any case, you're placing views within views (although it's bad practice to call a view directly from within another view).

One way to achieve this would be to load your internal views into an array, then pass that array into your layout view:

```
// Get ID From Segment
$id = $this->uri->segment(2);

// Get Article Data
$this->load->model('article');
$article = $this->article->getArticle($id);

// Define Layout View(s)
$layout['title']       = $article->title;
$layout['keywords']    = $article->keywords;
$layout['description'] = $article->description;
$layout['content']     = $this->load->view('articles/detail',array(
    'body'  => $article->body;
),true);

// Render Layout
$this->load->view('layouts/default',$layout);
```